# Overriding BadRequest response in ASP.NET Core ResourceFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am implementing a resource filter to store invalid requests in database and override returned BadRequest response.

I stored invalid requests successfully but I am struggling with overriding response, I tried the following:

```
public class MyFilter : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        ;
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //store request in data base
            context.Result= new BadRequestObjectResult(new MyErrorModel(){ID = "1",FriendlyMessage = "Your request was invalid"});
        }
    }
}

public class MyErrorModel
{
    public string FriendlyMessage { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

But the returned response is not being overridden.
Is there a way to override the response inside Resource filters?

P.S: I am using [ApiController] attribute.

Answer (score 3):

As we all kown , the `IResourceFilter` runs immediately after the authorization filter and is suitable for short-circular .

However , you will make no influence on the result by setting `Result=new BadRequestObjectResult()` when the result execution has finished .

See the workflow as below :

[image]

According to the workflow above , we should run the `MyFilter` after the stage of model binding and before the stage of result filter . In other words , we should put the logic into a action filter . Since there's already a  `ActionFilterAttribute` out of box , just create a `MyFilterAttribute` which inherits from the `ActionFilterAttribute` :

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //store request in data base
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new MyErrorModel() { ID = "1", FriendlyMessage = "Your request was invalid" });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot the filter works :

[image]

**[Edit]:**

The code of controller decorated with `[ApiController]`:

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Hello")]
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        [MyFilter]
        [HttpGet("index")]
        public IActionResult Index(int x)
        {
            var y =ModelState.IsValid;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as explained in my question, I need to store invalid requests, the invalid requests will not reach ActionFilters because model binding will fail

Comment: @YahyaHussein  I can't understand why those invalid requests can not reach ActionFilters . The model binding happens just before ActionFilters . Whether the model binding fails or not , the ActionFilters.ActionExecuting() will be the next stage , and then will skip the rest if we have the Result propoerty set .

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using  [ApiController] attribute, I don't want to lose auto validation

Comment: @YahyaHussein I've just tested the code above with a [ApiController] .  It makes no difference whether we use a [ApiController] or not .

Comment: it makes on my end :\, are u using .Net core 2.1?

Comment: @YahyaHussein Yes . I'm using .Net Core 2.1

Comment: @YahyaHussein I updated my reply and post the code of controller with `[ApiController]` decorated  .  If it doesn't works  on your side , please feel free to update me .

Comment: In my case it's the same, model validation, validation of anti forgery token all just respond and filter is never applied.